# Como inserir slide de 2 imagens (html)?

Tags: html, slide

```
<div id="home" style="background-image: url(assets/images/slider-1-background.jpg); width: 100%; height: 862px;" class="parallax hidden-xs">
```

Estou usando esse código no header com uma imagem, como posso inserir outra imagem de fundo e fazer com que elas fiquem mudando entre 5 segundos?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar `setInterval` (temporizador permanente). Crie duas variáveis com o caminho das imagens e vá alternando entre as duas:

```js
var img_1 = true;
setInterval(function(){
   
   var img1 = "url(https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg)";
   var img2 = "url(https://image.freepik.com/fotos-gratis/hrc-tigre-siberiano-2-jpg_21253111.jpg)"
   var el = document.querySelector("#home");

   img_1 ? (img_1 = false, img_exibir = img2) : (img_1 = true, img_exibir = img1);
   
   el.style.backgroundImage = img_exibir;
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div id="home" style="background-image: url(https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg); width: 100%; height: 862px;" class="parallax hidden-xs">
```

Comment: Gostei do método,muito bom e simples! +1 :D

Comment: Serviu perfeitamente esse método!!

Comment: @RafaelPrado Legal! Se puder marque a resposta como aceita ✓